# Intersection of two volumes

Tags: geometry, regions, intersection

I would like to know the volume of the intersection of a cone and a cuboid :

```
len=150;
wid=70;
dep=600;

phi=30;

vol1[h_] := Cone[{{len/2, wid/2, 0}, {len/2, wid/2, -h}}, h*Tan[phi Degree]];

vol2 = 
  Parallelepiped[{0, 0, 0}, {{len, 0, 0}, {0, wid, 0},
    {0, 0, -dep}}];

RegionIntersection[vol2, vol1[200]];

Volume[%]
```

But this doesn't work..

Could you help me ?

Comment: Might help: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51980/difference-or-intersection-of-two-convex-polyhedra.

Comment: You should give values to `longueur`,`largeur`,`profondeur` and `phi`.

Comment: I've forgotten this part of the code, it's now added

Comment: Works for me in 10.3, result `2100000-(125 (420 Sqrt[274]+686 ArcSinh[15/7]-3375 Log[-7+Sqrt[274]]+3375 Log[7+Sqrt[274]]))/Sqrt[3]`

Comment: Does a Graphics3D work also ?

Comment: Yes, using `RegionPlot3D`

Comment: Thank you, Volume was very slow on my computer, so I thought it was not working...

Comment: So is there another to compute this in a much faster way ?

Comment: If you are okay with an inexact result you could use machine precision values for the inputs (e.g. 150.0 instead of 150) which will be much faster

Comment: Ok thank you for your help !