# Intersection of two convex polyhedra with different set of faces

Tags: computational-geometry, intersection, polyhedra

I want to solve the same question as the one in

[Difference (or intersection) of two convex polyhedra](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51980/difference-or-intersection-of-two-convex-polyhedra)

however my two convex polyhedra have two different set of faces f1 and f2, for example, not only one as in the mentioned reference.

---

I tried to adapt from the metioned reference as following, but Mathematica keeps on running forever with no answer. Can someone see the mistake?

```
v1 = {{1/2, -(Sqrt[2]/3), 1/Sqrt[6]}, {1/2, Sqrt[2]/3, 1/Sqrt[6]}, {-(1/2), -(Sqrt[2]/3), 1/Sqrt[6]}, {-(1/2), Sqrt[2]/3, 1/Sqrt[6]}, {1/2, -(Sqrt[2]/3), -(1/Sqrt[6])}, {1/2, Sqrt[2]/3, -(1/Sqrt[6])}, {-(1/2), -(Sqrt[2]/3), -(1/Sqrt[6])}, {-(1/2), Sqrt[2]/3, -(1/Sqrt[6])}} 

f1={{8,4,2,6},{8,6,5,7},{8,7,3,4},{4,3,1,2},{1,3,7,5},{2,1,5,6}};

R = Graphics3D@GraphicsComplex[v1, Polygon /@ f1];

v2={{1/6, -(1/(6 Sqrt[2])), -(Sqrt[(3/2)]/2)}, {1/6, -(Sqrt[2]/3), -(1/Sqrt[6])}, {-(1/6), 1/(6 Sqrt[2]), -(Sqrt[(3/2)]/2)}, {-(1/2), 0, -(1/Sqrt[6])}, {-(1/6), -(5/(6 Sqrt[2])), -(1/(2 Sqrt[6]))}, {-(1/2), -(1/(2 Sqrt[2])), -(1/(2 Sqrt[6]))}, {1/2, 0, -(1/Sqrt[6])}, {1/2, -(1/(2 Sqrt[2])), -(1/(2 Sqrt[6]))}, {1/2, 1/(2 Sqrt[2]), -(1/(2 Sqrt[6]))}, {1/2, 1/(2 Sqrt[2]), 1/(2 Sqrt[6])}, {1/2, -(1/(2 Sqrt[2])), 1/(2 Sqrt[6])}, {1/2, 0, 1/Sqrt[6]}, {-(1/6), Sqrt[2]/3, -(1/Sqrt[6])}, {-(1/2), 1/(2 Sqrt[2]), -(1/(2 Sqrt[6]))}, {1/6, 5/(6 Sqrt[2]), -(1/(2 Sqrt[6]))}, {1/6, 5/(6 Sqrt[2]), 1/(2 Sqrt[6])}, {-(1/2), 1/(2 Sqrt[2]), 1/(2 Sqrt[6])}, {-(1/6), Sqrt[2]/3, 1/Sqrt[6]}, {-(1/6), -(5/(6 Sqrt[2])), 1/(2 Sqrt[6])}, {-(1/2), -(1/(2 Sqrt[2])), 1/(2 Sqrt[6])}, {1/6, -(Sqrt[2]/3), 1/Sqrt[6]}, {1/6, -(1/(6 Sqrt[2])), Sqrt[3/2]/2}, {-(1/2), 0, 1/Sqrt[6]}, {-(1/6), 1/(6 Sqrt[2]), Sqrt[3/2]/2}}

f2 = {{2, 1, 3, 4, 6, 5}, {8, 7, 9, 10, 12, 11}, {14, 13, 15, 16, 18, 
17}, {20, 19, 21, 22, 24, 23}, {2, 1, 7, 8}, {4, 3, 13, 14}, {6, 
5, 19, 20}, {10, 9, 15, 16}, {12, 11, 21, 22}, {18, 17, 23, 
24}, {20, 6, 4, 14, 17, 23}, {12, 22, 24, 18, 16, 10}, {21, 19, 5,
 2, 8, 11}, {15, 13, 3, 1, 7, 9}};

V = Graphics3D@GraphicsComplex[v2, Polygon /@ f2]

linePoly[v1_, v2_, f1_, f2_] := Module[{fC = Append[#, #[[1]]] & /@ f1}, 
  {x, y, z} /. NSolve[Or @@ ({x, y, z} ∈ # & /@ 
   MeshPrimitives[MeshRegion[v1, Line /@ fC], 1]) && Or @@ (
   {x, y, z}  ∈ # & /@ MeshPrimitives[MeshRegion[v2, Polygon /@ f2], 2])]
]; 

polysIntersected[v1_, v2_, f1_, f2_] := Union[linePoly[v1, v2, f1, f2], linePoly[v2, v1, f2, f1]]; 

points = polysIntersected[v1, v2, f1, f2] // Chop; 

Show[R, V]
Graphics3D[{PointSize[Large], Red, Point /@ points}];
Show[%, %%]
```